# Converting Message from RabbitMQ into string/json

Tags: java, json, spring, rabbitmq, amqp

I am currently struggling hard with a fair simple problem. I want to receive a message from RabbitMQ and have that transformed into a string (or later a json object). But all I get is bytes.

The *Message* object displays itself as a string that way

```
(Body:'{"cityId":644}'; ID:null; Content:application/json; Headers:{}; Exchange:; RoutingKey:pages.type.index; Reply:null; DeliveryMode:NON_PERSISTENT; DeliveryTag:1)
```

The configuration class (using spring)

```
@Configuration
public class RabbitConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory("www.example.com");
        connectionFactory.setUsername("xxxx");
        connectionFactory.setPassword("xxxx");
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter(){
        JsonMessageConverter jsonMessageConverter = new JsonMessageConverter();
        return jsonMessageConverter;
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleMessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer(){
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(connectionFactory());
        container.setAutoStartup(false);
        container.setQueues(indexQueue());
        container.setConcurrentConsumers(1);
        container.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.AUTO);
        container.setMessageListener(new MessageListenerAdapter(pageListener(), jsonMessageConverter()));
        return container;
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue indexQueue(){
        return new Queue("pages.type.index");
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageListener pageListener(){
        return new PageQueueListener();
    }

}
```

and the message listener

```
public class PageQueueListener implements MessageListener {

    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        System.out.println(message);
        System.out.println(message.getBody());
    }
 }
```

my problem is, that the *getBody()* method displayes *[B@4dbb73b0* so nothing is ever converted. Neither to a string nor to a json object :(

I feel stupid, but I cannot find a solution here

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`message.getBody()` returns a `byte[]`

Try:

```
byte[] body = message.getBody();
System.out.println(new String(body));
```

Comment: you are about to be kidding me... that worked, but how about the MessageConverter, doesn't that do anything?

Comment: Also if you look inside the source code for `org.springframework.amqp.core.Message` you'll find a method with signature `private String getBodyContentAsString()` which does it like this: `return new String(body, ENCODING);` ... therefore this should suffice as well: `System.out.println(new String(message.getBody(), Charset.defaultCharset().name()))`

Comment: I'm using getBody() method but it results out of memory exception exactly at the line of new String. Actually, after a long time running, it fails but the exception. Do you have any advice to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to parse to a JSONObject, the best way is add the RabbitMQ message to a StringBuilder in String format. Then parse the StringBuilder into a JSONObject, by using any of the conversion utils.
For e.g.:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(publisher.toString());
payload = (JSONObject)jsonParser.parse(sb.toString());
```